# twilio access token grants for voice documentation

Tags: twilio, token, voice

I have a browser based twilio phone app that works well, but for better security we are integrating access tokens now. But we can't find ANY documentation on grants anywhere.  We are constructing everything ourselves in our backend, so we are specifically looking for the variables we need to put in our JSON for that, for receiving calls and sending calls.

I have asked Twilio, but it's sunday.  When they return a response, if that comes first, and if it works, I'll put it here to help others who might be looking for this as we are.

ie. here is the JSON payload:

{"sub":"AC*****","nbf":1578251940,"iss":"SK*****","exp":1578338340,"iat":1578252060,"grants":{"identity":"ID_whatever","voice":{"service_sid":"AP*****"}},"jti":"SK*****"}

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you look here, https://www.twilio.com/docs/iam/access-tokens#jwt-format (and the code examples).

Comment: Yes thank you, that is how I got this far.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio have responded with a working payload template, here it is in case anyone else needs it.

```
{
  // API key SID concatenated with current timestamp
  "jti": "SK...-1578329486",
  // API key SID
  "iss": "SK...",
  // account SID
  "sub": "AC...",
  // expiration timesetamp
  "exp": 1578333086,
  "grants": {
    // Client name 
    "identity": "alice",
    "voice": {
      "incoming": {
      // if incoming connections are allowed
      "allow": true
    },
    "outgoing": {
      // if outgoing connections are allowed, the application SID
      "application_sid": "AP..."
    } 
  }
}
```